# Stretching ListView to a single screen?

Tags: android, listview

A simple ListView with, say, 6 rows (Views). Now, I want it to fit exactly a single screen. Any straightforward way to do this? Or should I go with a custom view?

Comment: Is the issue that the current view doesn't take up the full screen or takes up more than a full screen?  How would you like to react to screen orientation changes?

Comment: Doesn't matter, it takes almost full screen and I want it to be exactly full screen. The app is portrait-only. Gone with a custom View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gone with a custom View.

Couple of snippets:
PreferenceCategory-like TextView:

```
<TextView style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>
```

ListView separators:

```
<ImageView android:src="?android:attr/listDivider"android:layout_height="1dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is an straightforward way for this.

Define your own adapter class and then you'll have to resize the text size and other parameters for the TextViews that appear in your ListView so as to just fit within your screen.

Answer (score -3):

There is no straight forward way to do it. The best possible way is to enclise your listview in a div and add overflow to it. This would make it apper, that the list is in a iframe. See this -->

```
style type="text/css">
<!--
div.scroll {
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
overflow: auto;
border: 1px solid #666;
background-color: #ccc;
padding: 8px;
}
-->
</style> 


<div class="scroll">
<asp:ListView id="ListView1"...../>
</div>
```

See this --> http://www.domedia.org/oveklykken/css-div-scroll.php